# Asus Eee PC 1015CX shows resolution of 800x600 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, screen, ubuntu-netbook, asus, eeepc

I have Asus Eee PC 1015CX and I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.04, when I used the bootable USB and tried it, the only available option for resolution setting was 800x600 which looks bad on the screen.

There is no other option on the menu. How can I enable higher resolution?

Comment: Did you finish the installation?

Comment: same problem.. any updates?

Comment: What is the output (run in terminal) of `xrandr -q` ?

Comment: Hi, I have not installed it because I just wanted to try it. And unfortunately I am a newbie so I am not sure how to check the xrandr -q also because I have just tried it all the changes wont take effect and in order to post on the forum I would have to turn the system on and off all the time to switch between Ubuntu and Windows. 

Do you think that I should install it and then perhaps the problem would be gone?

Comment: @pl1nk I have installed ubuntu and typed the command that you suggested. There was the following output:
xrandr failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: Minimum 800x600, current 800x600, maximum 800x600
  Default connected 800x600+0+0 0mmx0mm
800x600 61.0*

Comment: What`s the resolution you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:
Once updated to 12.10 the additional drivers are automatically added enabling 1024X600 by default. However some problems still exist with the hot keys and screen brightness not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution - http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11976680&postcount=97

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.